# How to use an imported Excel file inside Anylogic model

Tags: excel, properties, dataset, anylogic

I have detailed wind historical data on an Excel sheet, (Speed and Direction) categorized by hour, day, month, and year, and I have imported the file into Anylogic by the builtin tool, however, I searched and I knew that in order to use the data in the Excel file I have to include the data into a Data Set, but I can't find any field in the "Properties" of the Data set that can link the Excel sheet to this Data set, anyone can help me do that?

what I want to do is for the Anylogic to check the table (row by row for each hour of the day) and create a dynamic variable, so when the wind speed is larger than a certain number (for example 10 m/s), then this wind speed will trigger another condition.

I have tried the Anylogic help, I asked Chat GPT 3.5, but its knowledge stops at the Anylogic version of January 2022, so it's not that recent, and I tried finding a few papers but with no luck.

Comment: Yes I have watched a video than inserted the Excel file on an Experiment, and created a parameter to read from the Excel file, but he defined a specific cell using the code (getCellNumericValue (String sheetName, int rowIndex, int columnIndex), but what I need is to link the parameter into an entire column, so I can link this with an event to creat a condition for wind speed, and loop it over the entire column to keep checking the values during operating hours, I can't find that unfortunately.